# Python and Selenium - Get element that is visible

Tags: python, selenium

Using **Python 3**.

**Situation**:

I select some elements with a certain xpath query.

There are many matches for that xpath query.

I want to grab the exact match corresponding with the element that is visible at the moment.

**Notes**:

There are always N matches *(being N greater than 1.)*

There is always only one match that is visible.

Actually, this is about pop-ups being displayed or not with javascript at certain moments.

**Question**:

How can iterate on all those results and know which one is visible by the user?

**UPDATE**:

The website is: [go to website](https://www.savoo.es/c-Alimentacion-codigo-promocional.html#p-5204957)

If you wait a few seconds, there is a popup being displayed.

My xpath query is:

`//div[@class='wrapper-code-reveal']//input[@class='code']`

But there are 23 matches in this case.

How may I get the exact match that is being displayed?

I tried clicking it, which would give an exception when not visible.

```
codigos_descuento = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrapper-code-reveal']//input[@class='code']")

for codigo in codigos_descuento:
    try:
        codigo.click()
        codigo_descuento_texto = codigo.get_attribute('value')
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example with Selenium. Instead of fiddling with finding the correct one by visibility, I get the offer ID from the URL and use that to find the correct element.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def get_offer_id_from_url(url):
    offer_id = url.split('#')[1]
    offer_id = offer_id.split('-')[1]
    return offer_id


def get_discount_code(url, offer_id):
    offer_div_id = 'd-%s' % offer_id
    driver.get(url)
    discount_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//div[@id='%s']//input[@class='code']" % offer_div_id
    )
    discount_code = discount_elem.get_attribute('value')
    return discount_code


url = 'https://www.savoo.es/c-Alimentacion-codigo-promocional.html#p-5204957'
offer_id = get_offer_id_from_url(url)
discount_code = get_discount_code(url, offer_id)
print(discount_code)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tito Paco. :) Wish you a great day.

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes a little late but I think one of the ways to check if the element is visible is simply by checking its location on the screen.
visible_elem = None

```
for elem in codigos_descuento:
    if elem.location["x"] > 0 and elem.location["y"] >0:
        visible_elem = elem
        print("Visible Element found!")
        break
```